# Extracting data from react redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an action that is getting some information from my back end, with this action:

```
export const getGroup = id => dispatch => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/group/${id}`)
    .then(res => {
      if (res.data === null) {
        throw { error: "no group found" };
      }
      dispatch({
        type: GET_GROUP,
        payload: res.data
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err
      })
    );
};
```

I mapped the data using mapStateToProps, and I assigned the data to a variable using destructuring -

```
const { group } = this.props.group;
```

console.log(group) gives me this:

```
{passwordenabled: true, _id: "5b04a644533447437c4bb4a7", groupname: "ddsafdsfadfas", email: "2@2.com", password: "$2a$10$qXZsWtyhySGv4hrSCIXq2.0Yl9kjK8qYLUPkNPo1LfjZujbNeED.W", …}
```

However, when I try to access the groupname property it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'groupname' of undefined
```

The object in console.log contains the property groupname: "ddsafdsfadfas" and typeof reveals object, but I'm still unable to access the property directly. I don't understand why I'm getting this error?

Edit: full mapStateToProps code -

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  group: state.group,
  errors: state.errors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGroup })(Dashboard);
```

Comment: Where and when do you accessed the `groupname` . The above api call is asynchronous and you might be accessing before a response is receive. The place where is you accessed is important. Pls update that.

Comment: I am accessing the property inside the render() method of a react component. Console.logging the object prints the data but accessing the 
 actual property then gives me the error.

Comment: Can you please paste the mapStateToProps code?

Comment: edited question with mapStateToProps code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be the asynchronous object. You are trying to access the value of an object that is fed by an asynchronous operation. Try some lil checking and see. Try

```
const { group } = this.props.group;
if(group) {
  console.log('The groupname is', group.groupname);
}
```

Does your console ever get executed ?

Comment: Yes, it does print to console with that code. I just noticed now that using console.log(group) gives an undefined result right at the beginning as well...so it seems the render is being called once before and after the props are being assigned...

Comment: I fixed it by adding a loading screen...seems I was misunderstanding when exactly render() was being called. Thanks